# Problema com escopo de variáveis internas do loop for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs

A minha função `gerarContatosChamado` retorna uma tabela HTML formatada com os valores que ela recebe do parâmetro `records`, isso funciona corretamente a tabela vem toda formatada com os dados certos de todos os contatos.

O problema acontece na linha `href` onde chamo a função: `gerenciarContatosChamado(\'atualizar\',resposta.contato,\'table\')`

o console alega que a variável resposta está indefinida, o que é estranho pois eu consigo usar ela dentro de todo o for depois que ela é retornada do da função de execução imediata.

O código:

```
function gerarContatosChamado(records)
{
var contatosTable = '';
    contatosTable += 
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>'+
        'Nome'+
    '</td>'+
    '<td style="text-align:center !important;">'+
        'Telefones'+
    '</td>'+
    '<td style="text-align:center !important;">'+
        'Email'+
    '</td>'+
    '<td style="text-align:center !important;">'+
        'Horários para contato'+
    '</td>'+
    '<td style="text-align:center !important;">'+
        'Opções do contato'+
    '</td>'+
'</tr>';

    var Contatos = records.get('Contatos');
    for (var i=0;i < Contatos.length;i++)
    { 
        var resposta = function(j)
        {
            var objeto = {};
            var contatoChamadoModel = Ext.create('contatoChamado.Model', {
            idContato : records.get('Contatos')[j].idContato,
            nomeContato : records.get('Contatos')[j].nomeContato,
            telefonesContato  : records.get('Contatos')[j].telefonesContato,
            emailContato: records.get('Contatos')[j].emailContato, 
            horariosContato: records.get('Contatos')[j].horariosContato,
            tipoHorarioContato: records.get('Contatos')[j].tipoHorarioContato      
            });
            objeto.contato = contatoChamadoModel;
            return objeto;
        }(i);

//  protocoloChamado: records.get('protocoloChamado')


        //var aux_TelefonesContato=itensContato[1].split(",");
        //var aux_TiTleTelefonesContato='Telefones: \n';
    //  var horariosContato;
    //  if(contato.tipoHorarioContato == 1)
        //horariosContato = '24 horas';
        //else if (contato.tipoHorarioContato == 2)
        //horariosContato = 'horário comercial';
        //else
        //horariosContato = 'personalizado: '+contato.horariosContato;



        contatosTable +=
        '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+
            resposta.contato.get('nomeContato')+
        '</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            resposta.contato.get('telefonesContato')+
        '</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            resposta.contato.get('emailContato')+
       '</td>'+
        '<td style="text-align:center !important">'+
            resposta.contato.get('horariosContato')+
        '</td>'+
        '<td style="text-align:center !important">'+
            '<a href="javascript:gerenciarContatosChamado(\'atualizar\',resposta.contato,\'table\')">Modificar</a> <img src="../extjs/shared/icons/fam/user_edit.png"> <a href="javascript:void(0)"'+ 
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>';
    }

    return '<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >'+
            '<table >'+
               '<tr>'+
                    '<td colspan=5>'+
                        'Contatos'+
                    '</td>'+                        
                '</tr>'+
                contatosTable
            + '</table>'+
        '</div>';

}
```

Comment: Quando você chama `gerenciarContatosChamado` usando JavaScript *inline*, qualquer referência a variável precisa ser global, e por isso `resposta` está fora de escopo. Não vai ter como você passar esse objeto sem uma mudança mais radical nesse código.

Comment: Sobre a formatação da pergunta, até que está razoável :) Explique o que você não conseguiu fazer que a gente te ensina.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rápida. Sobre a formatação não cosnegui identar o código e esqueci de mencionar que ali na parte resposta.contato.get('variavel') a resposta é retornada corretamente, o que pode ser então que ela nao funciona dentro do href?

Comment: De nada. Só não postei como resposta mesmo (no campo mais abaixo) porque estou sem tempo de elaborar uma solução completa.

Comment: Aquele código no href só é executado quando você clicar no link. E aí ele vai procurar uma variável `resposta` global, que não existe, quando na verdade você queria um objeto resposta específico que você gera durante o loop e está fora de escopo. Depois vejo se consigo te dar um caminho, se ninguém fizer isso antes. Sobre a formatação, o site não lida bem com tabs, se você usar sempre espaços para indentar fica ok.

Comment: Tente evitar javascript inline no html, acho que a solução seria mais por aí.

Answer (score 1):

A função "resposta" está dentro de um loop, toda iteração do loop a função é recriada e não pode ser acessada fora do loop. Você pode colocar ela fora do loop.
Indo mais a fundo, a função "resposta" é desnecessária neste caso pois você poderia executar todo o procedimento em sequencia sem a necessidade da função.
Mas acho que não é este o problema.

Existem outros problemas aparentes que precisam ser verificados, notei que você está utilizando o ExtJS (eu também uso este excelente framework). Percebi que você está criando o model mas na criação falta o namespace do seu APP e a logica esta invertida, você coloca `Ext.create('contatoChamado.Model')` deveria ser algo como: `Ext.create('APPNAMESPACE.model.contatoChamado', {});`

Outra coisa `var Contatos = records.get('Contatos');` retorna um contato apenas, e não uma lista, não faz sentido o loop em seguida. Use o filter em vez do get.

Outro pontos para vc verificar:

- Use o Ext.xtemplate para compor o html, fica muito melhor e eficiente.
- Utilize os loops fornecidos pelo EXT, (store.for_each) eles são otimizados para os stores.
- Separe os pedaços de código para melhorar a leitura.

Por fim, sugiro que você reveja a documentação do ExtJS sobre models e stores.